# OpenGL: why the spheres with same X coordinate are not in a straight in the output?

Tags: c++, opengl

I am working on a C++ project and it is written in MFC Templates;
using the OpenGL Library I am drawing the spheres in a special coordinate. I go to this special coordinate with `glTranslatef` function, but when I draw two spheres with the same X coordinates, it look likes they have a difference in their `x`.

For example when I draw two sphere in `(x,y,z):(1,1,0)`, and `(x,y,z):(1,2,0)` the output is this:

[image: the picture for my output]

this view is from the above: 
[image]

This is my function for drawing the spheres:

```
void MYGLView::DrawSphere(double X_position, double Y_Position, double Z_Position,
    GLdouble radius, int longitudeSubdiv, int latitudeSubdiv,
    double Red, double Green,double Blue)
{
    gluQuadricDrawStyle(m_quadrObj, GLU_FILL);

    float shininess = 64.0f;
    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(X_position,Y_Position,Z_Position);
    glColor3f(Red,Green,Blue);
    gluSphere(m_quadrObj,radius,longitudeSubdiv,latitudeSubdiv);
    //glTranslatef(-3,0,0);
    glFlush();
    glPopMatrix();
}
```

Can you tell me where I make the mistake?

Comment: while glPushMatrix pushes the matrix onto the stack and glPopMatrix restores it, glTranslatef uses the previous matrix as a frame of reference. So likely the frame of reference is scaled/skewed/rotated as the result of a previous draw routine - maybe you intend to do a glLoadIdentity to 'reset' it.

Comment: I added them just for testing the output;) without them the problem still exists!

Answer (score 3):

your camera is slightly turned downwards. Therefore you have a vanishing point for all vertical lines. If you want that all vertical lines are parallel on the screen your camera is not allowed to tilt downwards. Alternatively you can use parallel projection, where all lines that are parallel in the world remain parallel in the image.

Comment: do you mean "Parallel Projection" is a separate concept which I study that? what do you mean ? I dont think that the direction of the camera  is the problem. because when I rotate the scene and look from the bottom of the spheres, the upper marker seems to have greater x;

Comment: you mean when you look from the top, not the bottom. It has to do with the fact that in perspective projection everiything that is close to the camera is scaled up, and everything far away from the camera is scaled down. Parallel projection behaves different. For easiest example, download blender, add some cubes and rotate your camera around, then press Numpad_5 to acitvate parallele projection and see the diffirence.